# Integration of $\frac{1}{\sin^2(x) + 2\cos^2(x)}$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ by anti derivate method

Tags: integration

I want to calculate this integral without residue theorem: $$ \int_0^{2\pi}  \frac{1}{\cos^2(x) +2\sin^2(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
 I know the antiderivative: $$ \int  \frac{1}{\cos^2(x) +2\sin^2(x)} \mathrm{d}x =  \frac{\arctan(\sqrt{2}\tan(x))}{\sqrt2}$$
When we substitute limits we get $0$, but the answer is $\pi\sqrt{2}$ which I calculated from residue therorem. How to fix this?

Comment: I would just re-write the denominator as $1+\cos^2(x)$ and then follow the technique found here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w998Muep76Q

Comment: @DanielSchepler, thanks for the comment, but this function is piecewise continuous. so this should be integrable right?

Comment: There is a typo. Please fixed it.

Comment: The integral is $4$ times the integral over $[0,\pi/2]$ (why?) and then use your anti-derivative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in the original argument is that if you treat $\arctan$ as being a function, for example choosing the principal branch which has range $(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$, then $F(x) = \frac{\arctan(\sqrt{2} \tan(x))}{\sqrt{2}}$ is not defined at $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$ or at $x = \frac{3\pi}{2}$.  What's more, $\lim_{x \to \pi/2^-} F(x) = \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}$ while $\lim_{x\to \pi/2^+} F(x) = -\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}$ so we cannot "fix up" $F$ to be a continuous function just by assigning values at $\pi/2$ and $3\pi/2$.  Therefore, $F$ does not satisfy the conditions to be an antiderivative for $f(x) = \frac{1}{\cos^2(x) + 2 \sin^2(x)}$ on the interval $[0, 2\pi]$ and we cannot apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

What we *can* do, however, is to shift the function by constants on the intervals where it is defined, in such a way that the resulting function becomes an antiderivative.  Namely, we will define:
$$ F(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{\arctan(\sqrt{2} \tan(x))}{\sqrt{2}}, & 0 \le x < \pi/2 \\
\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}, & x = \pi/2 \\
\frac{\arctan(\sqrt{2} \tan(x))}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}, & \pi/2 < x < 3\pi/2 \\
\frac{3\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}, & x = 3\pi/2 \\
\frac{\arctan(\sqrt{2} \tan(x))}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{2}}, & 3\pi / 2 < x \le 2\pi.\end{cases}$$
Here, we have chosen the constants to resolve the continuity problem.  It now remains to show that $F$ is also differentiable at $x=\pi/2$ and at $3\pi/2$, with the correct value of the derivative.  To do this, one possible approach would be to check that $F(x) = \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}} - \frac{\arctan(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cot(x))}{\sqrt{2}}$ for $0 < x < \pi$, and find a similar formula valid for $\pi < x < 2\pi$.

Once we have established this, we can now use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to conclude $\int_0^{2\pi} f(x)\,dx = F(2\pi) - F(0) = \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{2}} - 0 = \pi\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$I=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{dx}{\cos^2x+2\sin^2x}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{dx}{1+\sin^2x}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\csc^2x}{2+\cot^2x}dx=2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{du}{u^2+2}, $$

where $u=\cot x$. Since integrand is an even function and the interval is symmetric, one gets

$$I=4\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{du}{u^2+2}=\pi\sqrt{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\int_0^{2\pi}  \frac{1}{\cos^2(x) +2\sin^2(x)} dx\\
\int_0^{2\pi}  \frac{\sec^2 x}{1 +2\tan^2(x)} dx$

We want to do a substitution like:

$\sqrt 2 \tan x = \tan u\\
\sec^2 x \ dx = \frac {\sqrt{2}}{2} \sec^2 u\ du$

Since the substitution is not continuous, we need to break up the interval.

$\int_0^{2\pi}  \frac{\sec^2 x}{1 +2\tan^2(x)} dx + \int_\frac {\pi}{2}^{\frac {3\pi}{2}}  \frac{\sec^2 x}{1 +2\tan^2(x)} dx + \int_\frac {3\pi}{2}^{2\pi}  \frac{\sec^2 x}{1 +2\tan^2(x)} dx$

Then we need to do a substution along the lines of

$\sqrt 2 \tan x = \tan u$ for the first interval

$\sqrt 2 \tan (x-\pi) = \tan u$ for the second interval

$\sqrt 2 \tan (x-2\pi) = \tan u$ for the third interval

$\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \frac {\sqrt 2}{2}\frac{\sec^2 u}{1 +\tan^2(u)} du + \int_{-\frac {\pi}{2}}^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \frac {\sqrt 2}{2}  \frac{\sec^2 u}{1 +\tan^2(u)} du + \int_{-\frac {\pi}{2}}^0\frac{\sqrt 2}{2} \frac{\sec^2 u}{1 +\tan^2(u)} du$

$\frac{\sqrt 2}{2} (\frac {\pi}{2} + \pi + \frac {\pi}{2})  = \sqrt2 \pi$

Comment: The OP already knew that.

Comment: @Frpzzd you are fast.  I had almost immediately deleted this post in order to update it, and in that 30 seconds you managed to downvote me.. Hope this clears things up.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. Thanks for updating your post. :)

Answer (score 0):

The anti-derivative in not continuous on the interval $[0,2\pi]$, it has singularities on any point in $\{\frac{\pi}{2}+\pi k;\ k\in\mathbb{N}\}$. You need to find the integral on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ (using the same method you suggested) and then multiply the result by 4.